# Are all of the cases of LA Noire available in LA Noire The VR Case Files?

Tags: la-noire

Are all of the cases present in LA Noire and/or LA Noire Remaster available in the Virtual Reality release of LA Noire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the following cases are present in LA Noire: The VR Case Files:

- [Start](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/Start) (based on [Warrants Outstanding](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/Warrants_Outstanding), adapted for VR)
- [Armed and Dangerous](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/Armed_and_Dangerous)
- [Upon Reflection](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/Upon_Reflection)
- [Buyer Beware](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/Buyer_Beware)
- [The Consul's Car](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/The_Consul%27s_Car)
- [The Silk Stocking Murder](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/The_Silk_Stocking_Murder)
- [Reefer Madness](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/Reefer_Madness)
- [A Different Kind of War](https://lanoire.fandom.com/wiki/A_Different_Kind_of_War)